# VirtualBox Failover Cluster with iSCSI

Tags: virtualbox, iscsi, failovercluster

I have created 2 identical virtual machines running Windows Server 2008 r2 with the intention of creating a failover cluster environment.

I attached an iSCSI device as hard disk to both nodes, but since doing that can only start one of the 2 nodes at a time.

> failed to start machine. Error message: Locking of attached media
>   failed. A possible reason is that one of the media is attached to a
>   running VM

How do I configure the 2 guests so they can both 'see' a single iSCSI target, suitable as a cluster disk?

Comment: You need to create a failover cluster with the two nodes and add the iSCSI LUN as a Cluster Shared Volume.

Comment: Yes I figured that out - the answer is NOT to try and create the attachment in VirtualBox, but to do it from within the VMs.  Thanks, Joe

Comment: You might try using StarWind vSAN but I'm not sure it will work with WS2008R2. I'd suggest to go with at least WS2012R2 (WS2016?) at least.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am trying to emulate an existing production environment on my development kit using virtuals, so it has to be 2008 r2.  I got it working, btw. The answer was do not attach the device in VirtualBox - attach using the iSCSI initiator on the servers